# Fetching Data from SQL Server Through Shiny Application on Date selection bases

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, shiny, shiny-server

Hey Every One i am developing a Shiny Application, where we Extract a data from sql Server through ODBC Connector by selecting Date to and from in a Application. i am unable to identify where the issue is because if i execute the code independently on R studio i am able to extract the data from sql Server But then when the same code is executed in Shiny Environment i am unable to achieve the data on shiny here is the below Kindly Guide me on this Thank you.

```
# ---------------------ui Code -----------------------------
library(shiny) 

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar( 

  headerPanel("Time Analytics"), 

  sidebarPanel( 


      dateRangeInput(inputId = "dateRange",  
                     label =  "Date range",
                     start = "2007-09-17",
                     max = Sys.Date()
      )


  ),#sidebar Panel Ends


    # 09-Main Panel ----
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id ="theTabs",
                tabPanel("Summary", dataTableOutput("tabi"),textOutput("tabii")) 

    )
  )#Main Panel Ends
))

#------------------Server ----------------------------------



library(shiny);library(sqldf)
library(plyr);library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)


#Creating the connection 

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){ # pass in a session argument






  # prep data once and then pass around the program

  passData <- reactive({




    ch = odbcConnect("Test")  
    #qry <- "SELECT * FROM Nifty50"
    #qry <- cat("SELECT * FROM Nifty50 WHERE Date >= ",as.date(input$dateRange[1])," AND Date <= ",input$dateRange[2])
    qry <- paste("SELECT * FROM Nifty50 WHERE Date >= ",input$dateRange[1]," AND Date <= ",input$dateRange[2])
    #paste("SELECT * FROM Nifty50 WHERE Date >= ",input$dateRange[1]," AND Date <= ",input$dateRange[2])
    subset_Table <- sqlQuery(ch,qry)

    odbcClose(ch)
    subset_Table <- as.data.frame(subset_Table)
    return(subset_Table)

  })

  output$tabi <- renderDataTable({

    d<- as.data.frame(passData())
    d
  })

  output$tabii <- renderText({

    paste("Minimium Data :",input$dateRange[1], "Max Date:",input$dateRange[2])
  })




  # ----------------------------------------------------End

})
```

Here  the task is i need to fetch the data from selected Table on the bases of Date to and From criteria, which will be the subset data as per the selected Date from shiny app.

Comment: Do you get any errors, messages, or warnings?

Comment: @Benjamin no i did'nt get any error, i am clueless about this

Comment: Now i am able to fetch Data from SQL server But i need to subset with respect Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `qry` as follows:

```
qry <- paste("SELECT * FROM Nifty50 WHERE Date >= '", input$dateRange[1], "' AND Date <= '", input$dateRange[2], "'", sep = "")
```